# Use $row['col'] more than once on a page php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="professor_comments">
<?php                                                                        
                #Show User Who Submitted Content
                if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                     
                while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $theCommentID = $row['CommID'];
                    }
                }
                else {                                                       
                echo "No CommID";
                }

                echo "Value of CommID: $theCommentID";
                echo "<h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>";
                if ($sth22->rowCount()) {                                    
                while($row = $sth22->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {              
                    echo "<div class='comment'>by <em>{$row['uname']}</em>";
                    }
                }
                else {                                                       
                echo "User";
                }
                unset($sth22);
                #Show Recent Comments
                if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                     
                while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "on {$row['date']} about <code><a href='course.php?cID={$row['cID']}'>{$row['prefix']} {$row['code']}</a>&nbsp;</code>  during  {$row['Qtr']},  {$row['Yr']} <span style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'><img src='img/report.png' /> 
                    <a class='report' href='report.php?commID={$row['CommID']}'>Report</a></span><br />{$row['info']} </div>";
                    }                                                        
                }                                                            
                else {                                                       
                echo "<h2 style='color:red;'> No Comments Found, please add some below</div>";
                }
                unset($sth2);                                                                                                                
?>  

<?php
// Get any professor comments currently present ON LOAD
$pID2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', $u, $p);
        $pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
SELECT C.cID, Co.CommID, prefix, code, info, date, Qtr, Yr
FROM Course C, Comment Co, Professor P
WHERE P.pID = ?
AND C.cID = Co.CName AND P.pID = Co.pID 
ORDER BY Yr DESC;
             ');
        $sth2->execute(array(
            $pID2
        ));

?>
```

**PHP script behind**

```
   <?php
    // Get the user of the comment
    $pID22 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $pdo22 = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', $u, $p);
            $pdo22->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sth22 = $pdo22->prepare("
            SELECT uname FROM Student S, Comment C WHERE S.usrID = C.usrID and commID='$theCommentID';
                 ");
            $sth22->execute(array(
                $pID22
            ));

    ?>

This gives me the inital value of the commID outputted, but then seems to ignore all fetching for rows when :

    #Show Recent Comments
                        if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                     
                        while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

is called again. Why is it only outputted the first `commID` but then omitting this second call for `$sth2`  :

                #Show Recent Comments
            if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                     
                while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "on {$row['date']} about <code><a href='course.php?cID={$row['cID']}'>{$row['prefix']} {$row['code']}</a>&nbsp;</code>  during  {$row['Qtr']},  {$row['Yr']} <span style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'><img src='img/report.png' /> 
                <a class='report' href='report.php?commID={$row['CommID']}'>Report</a></span><br />{$row['info']} </div>";
                    }                                                        
                }                                                            
                else {                                                       
                echo "<h2 style='color:red;'> No Comments Found, please add some below</div>";
                }
                unset($sth2);
```

Question: I'm looking to use :

```
if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                    
                while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Twice in my code above and its not letting me and I'm not unsetting the code in the middle..

Comment: You could definitely have narrowed this down to a testcase, rather than bombarding us with all this PHP .. and HTML!?

Comment: Also try to find a smarter solution for printing out comments, which don't need six conditions and six loops, to do a single task.

Comment: I just need help using the commID twice in my page coming from ONE and ONLY ONE query. Please!!! 

// I realize I may not be the best php coder, but can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

`PDOStatement->fetch()` [Fetches the next row from a result set](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), so you can't use it again to retrieve the same value. Use [`PDOStatement->fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to fetch all results into a single array, which may be re-used.

Also you have `commID='$theCommentID'` in your WHERE-clause, which looks like this statement should only return one row - if it's so, there is no need for a loop.

```
$firstRow = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
/* $secondRow = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); */
```

Third, using PDO but not using parameter binding, is contrary to whole idea of save databse accesses.

```
// instead
$sth22 = $pdo22->prepare("SELECT uname FROM Student S, Comment C WHERE S.usrID = C.usrID and commID='$theCommentID';");
// better use something like
$sth22 = $pdo22->prepare('SELECT uname FROM Student S, Comment C WHERE S.usrID = C.usrID and commID=:comment_id');
$sth22->bindValue(':comment_id', $theCommentID);
```

Comment: Can you show me how to use fetchall() in my example and I'll try to implement it?

Comment: "Can you show me how to" To do that I'll need to know what exactly you want to achieve. Also, please read the manual, try it for yourself and come back with specific question.

Comment: How do I "reuse" the same row twice, so say for example I want to output commID twice, so $row['commID']. How do I use fetchall to do this?

Comment: @user886187 Just store into another variable in the first loop: `$commentId = $row['commID'];`, now you may reuse `$commentId` as often as you want.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal OK, don't saw that and never worked with `cursor_orientation` …nice hint.

Comment: Can you please show me an example with my code? I keep trying and blowing up my page? // Sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: @feeela: I've never even worked with PDO. I just read the documentation and translate it into an answer. :)

Comment: @user886187: It's already blown up! There's no chance we're going to show you an example with that behemoth. You're going to have to generate a small, isolated _testcase_, apply the fix to that testcase and then use your ingenuity to apply it to your larger program.

Answer (score 0):

As feeela explained, `PDOStatement::fetch` *by default* gives you the "next" record, so you can't just keep using it after you've already reached the end of the resultset.

The PDO interface has no knowledge that, in your PHP code, you're suddenly using a new, separate `while` loop for your calls to this function (and nor should it).

---

However, for certain types of resultsets it is possible to *reset* the cursor so that you may begin again at the beginning.

The manual page for [`PDOStatement::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) explains it:

- `PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS` for the 2nd arg
- `0` for the 3rd.

Be sure to read the manual properly, as it describes with which resultsets you can do this, and how to make it so for yours.

---

You can, instead, use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to retrieve and store all records at once, but this is pretty wasteful (in terms of at-a-time memory requirements) if it's not explicitly what you need to satisfy your functional requirements.

---

<sup>(It'd also be worthwhile heeding feeela's words regarding your `WHERE` issue, and regarding prepared statements.)</sup>

Comment: Please, example with my code would be the most beneficial. The php site is really bad for a beginner

Comment: @user886187 "The php site is really bad for a beginner" What? I can't comprehend that, as the most things I've learned about PHP, doesn't come from my university's teacher but the PHP-manual. That just sounds like you're lazy…

Comment: @user886187: If you're struggling with the PHP Manual, then the answer is _not_ to ignore it (which will just makes things worse), but to continue studying it for as long as you have to. Jumping into real-world examples is just shooting yourself in the foot as long as you don't have a clue what you're doing; it's like stealing a car and driving the wrong way down the motorway, because you found driving lessons a little bit difficult and gave them up.

Comment: Also, I have already explained that nobody is going to adapt the _behemoth_ of code that you threw at us! It sounds to me like you should find somebody to take you through this with your code _in person_. Stack Overflow has provided the answer, but step-by-step contextual tuition isn't really a good fit to our Q&A format.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you save each row in an array that you can use whenever

something like

```
$rows = array();

if ($sth2->rowCount()) {                                    
   while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
   }
}
```

then you can walk through $rows whenever you like and get the row you want, or just save one row if you only interested in one

Comment: Which is the same as `$rows = $sth2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` (don't rewrite build-in functions, as they are written in C)

Comment: Tristan, would you find showing me how to do this with my code? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: @feeela yes you can do it all in one shot using fetchAll, though i choose not to use this to show an example as close to possible as the askers example